# Are the following JavaScript syntactical elements operators?

Tags: javascript

Are the following JavaScript syntactical elements operators?

```
. // e.g. myObject.foo;
return // e.g. return 'foo';
[] // e.g. myObject['foo];
```

Definition of operator found on the interweb:

> ...an operator is a program element that is applied to one or more
>   operands in an expression or statement.

This might imply that `return` in:

```
return 'foo';
```

...is an operator with `'foo'` being the operand. Clearly this is a statement (fitting with the definition).

Comment: `.` and `[]` are member access operators whereas `return` is a statement.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: I can say for sure that `return` is not an operator. The others depend on your definition of operator.

Comment: @Ben Nope, its not mine... I was thinking you would clarify your question.

Comment: [These](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) are operators. Nothing else is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "operator" can be understood in two ways:

- (generic) a language construct that, when applied to a set of values, yields a new value. In this generic sense, yes, the dot is an operator, and so are brackets, but `return` isn't (because it doesn't produce any value). In an imperative language, an `expression` is defined recursively as

  ```
  expression = variable | literal | apply operator to expression(s)
  ```

  This way, everything in an expression that is not a variable or literal is an operator. For example,

  ```
  a = Math.sin(b[c])
  ```

  rewritten in the applicative syntax

  ```
  apply(=, a, 
     apply(<call>, 
        apply(., Math, sin), 
        apply([], b, c)))
  ```

  reveals that there are 4 operators here: `=`, function call (`()`), dot and brackets.
- (language-specific) whatever a particular language standard calls an "operator". In Javascript, dots and brackets are not called operators, but [property accessors](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1).

Comment: I presume `apply` is a conceptual function to apply an operator to operands? Can you point me to a resource on the applicative syntax?

Comment: "`return`... doesn't produce any value". Naively `return` might be said to produce the result of the expression on the right. But you are saying that this is incorrect? I'm talking in the generic sense.

Comment: @Ben: if `return` had a value, then this value could be combined with other values, like `5 + return 10` - but that's impossible. Regarding "applicative syntax", in my answer this simply means that we (theoretically) can express any operator uniformly as `apply(operator,arg1,arg2....)`.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not operators, at least not in the same sense as for example mathematical operator. They are sometimes called operators, but they are rather language constructs as they don't work with regular values.

The `.` and `[]` (as used in the examples) are the [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

The `return` keyword is used for a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

---

An operator are used with one or more operands. The `.` is not an operator in this case, because what comes after it is not an operand, it's an identifier.

The `[]` is more similar to an operator, but it's a language construct as it only applies to a certain kind of values.

The `return` keyword isn't an operator because it doesn't form an expression that has a value.

Comment: From MDN: "Property accessors: Member operators provide access to a property or method of an object (object.property and object["property"])." This indicates that `.` and `[]` are "member operators".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: Property accessors are definitely operators; they're part of the expression grammar.

Comment: @Guffa If I clarify that I am talking specifically within the context of programming languages, does that change your answer? Surely in `myObject.foo`, `myObject` and `foo` are the operands, `.` is the operator. Indeed Wikipedia includes `.` in its opening paragraph on the subject.